wp_verify_nonce is always false even when the nonces are identical
In a plugin i create a nonce with a time limit of 15 minutes:
function noncelife(){ return 900; }
add_action( 'run_custom_nonce_value', 'custom_nonce_value' );
    function custom_nonce_value(){
    add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );
    $created_nonce = wp_create_nonce('timform_nonce');
    remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );

    return $created_nonce;
    }

With wp_localize_script i send the nonce to a jquery file enqueued in the plugin:
wp_localize_script( 'timcontact', 'ctfprocessajax', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
                                                      'formnonce' => custom_nonce_value() ) );

The ajax function in my jquery file sends all data via admin-ajax.php with the appropriate action name to wp_process_timform.php that contains the send e-mail function.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_toaformsendmail', 'timform_sendmail' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_toaformsendmail', 'timform_sendmail' );

function timform_sendmail() {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (isset($_POST['nonce']) && !empty($_POST['nonce'])){
           $nonce = $_POST['nonce'];
           } else {
           $nonce = ''; 
           }

    if(! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'timform_nonce' )){ //always false
       echo $nonce; //is identical but does not validate
       die( 'Security check' );
       } else {
       // Send the email.
    if (wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $message_send, $headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "<p class=\"timform-okmessage\">Thanks etc.</p>";
    } else {
           // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
           http_response_code(500);
           echo "Error";
        }
        die();
        }
    }
}

The function works perfect without the wp_verify_nonce condition, but with wp_verify_nonce the condition always returns false. Why is this not validating when the nonces are identical? Is wp_verify_nonce not reachable via a plugin?

Does it work without the filter to change the time limit?

I’ll check that. Yes, it does. Thanks. But the time is too long. No way to make this work with shortening the life time of a nonce?

If you put the same nonce_life filters around the verify function it should work.

How does this apply to a condition? Like so: if ( ! isset( $nonce ) || add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'mynoncelife' ) ! wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'toaformsendmail' ) remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'mynoncelife' ) ) ?

Do you mean why does that work? Nonces contain time as a number of ticks, where each tick is half the nonce lifetime long. If you have a different lifetime it computes the number of ticks differently and so the nonces don't match.

If you meant how to write the code to add and remove the filter, you could save the verify result into a variable, remove the filter then check the variable is true or false.

all your code gets loaded into memory, and once that's happened it doesn't really matter where the code came from, so unless you're making a direct request to wp_process_timform.php ( which would be a very bad thing to do ), the phrase "The ajax function in my jquery file sends it to" is meaningless. For the same reasons the question " Is wp_verify_nonce not reachable via a plugin?" doesn't make sense. What's more likely is that the filter on noncelife is problematic here. It's also possible that a logic error is being hidden by the incorrect indenting.

Also when you say the nonce is identical, what is it identical to? If you mean it's identical to the value that was localised and generated then that doesn't mean the nonce is valid, just that you passed the nonce to the AJAX succesfully where it was then rejected. Keep in mind that the value of noncelife is also used when checking a nonces validity so you can't add then remove the filter and expect that nonce to work everywhere

@Tom J Nowell. Thanks for the comments. How else can i access wp_process_timform.php, than with sending data via ajax? Is there a better method and where can i learn this better technique?

the admin ajax API uses wp-admin/admin-ajax.php that's where you would make HTTP requests to, or you could register a REST API endpoint and get a pretty URL. You would never make direct HTTP requests to a PHP file in a theme or plugin folder. As for where the code is located, as long as it's include/include_once/require/require_once/etc it doesn't matter

@ Tom J Nowell – thanks for the specification. Acutally i did that, but missed to express myself consicely. The part with wp_localize_script shows that admin-ajax.php is involved.

Nonces don't store absolute time, but the number of 'ticks' since the start of the unix epoch, where each tick is half a day long by default. To check a nonce, WordPress generates the current and previous nonces and compares the result to the value you passed in.
This means that the nonce lifetime needs to match at the point you create the nonce and at the point you verify it. You could implement that using your filters again, e.g.
add_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );
$valid_nonce = wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'timform_nonce' );
remove_filter( 'nonce_life', 'noncelife' );
if ( ! $valid_nonce ) {

('store' is probably the wrong word: they're actually hashes of a constructed string. There's no way to extract information from a nonce the same way there is from an encrypted cookie.)

Thanks for the code.
